# android layout design looking good only in graphical layout not in devices

Tags: android, android-layout

i tried designing an xml layout for my android app. It looks good in eclipse graphical layout of android api level 10. But when i run the same in my android device of 2.3.3(api level 10),
that layout looks completely different.

After the text title in the top everything gets changed

I have attached the screen shot of my graphical layout in eclipse and image from my android device

[image]

Following is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame2_include"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top">
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/title_include"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/title" />  
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/r_title_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/title_bg">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/normal_title_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/app"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/r_frame_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/r_title_layout">

                <ViewSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/r_frame_viewSwitcher1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/r_frame_image_layout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="7dp"
                        android:background="@color/white" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/r_round_points"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/points_bg" >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/r_center_frame_img_layout"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true">
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/r_frame_img_txt1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textSize="30dp"
                                    android:text="50"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/r_frame_img_txt2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/Points"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/r_frame_map_layout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">                    
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/parii_me_map_view2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            layout="@layout/parii_map" />   
                    </LinearLayout>
            </ViewSwitcher>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/r_merge_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/merge_bg_img"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/title_bg" 
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/merge_view_pro_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/merge_view_pro_txt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mrg_profile"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_width="73dp"
                    android:layout_height="73dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/merge_view_cash_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/merge_center_img"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/merge_view_cash_txt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@string/mrg_cash"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/r_edit_box_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="185dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r_remaining_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="200"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/ponts_field"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r_remaining_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r_remaining_label"
                    android:text="@string/Reamins"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r_points_txt"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/r_points_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Parii_Pts"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r_points_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/ponts_field"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />
            </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r_items_viewed_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r_frame_layout"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/r_bottom_map_layout"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/r_items_viewed_txt"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
          <TextView
               android:id="@+id/r_valid_date"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/r_points_label"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

          <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:id="@+id/parii_me_details_switch_mapBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/map_sel_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Pls say me where i am going wrong

Comment: use relative layout as parent instead of frame layout

Comment: no use, still the same error.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

only replace that by default image by your circle image having 50 pts inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#aba4a4">


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/l1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back btn"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rewards"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
        android:background="#7d7373">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:background="#7d7373"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

   <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add the remaining view in it.i think this must solve your issue.

Comment: thanx for the solutions, but it does not match with my layout. I want to place a rounded background with some textview and that text and round background should be placed over a image. if the image size is large the center bars need to be moved down. But in your idea they all are fixed in center...

Comment: i already told you replace that by default image by your rounded image.And if you dont want them to be centered than remove centerinparent="true"

Comment: but you have set the circle as its background.so replace by this.

Comment: thanx i got it with some modifications in your xml